# Lie algebras of vector fields over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $S^1$

Tags: differential-topology, lie-algebras, vector-fields

An exercise in the book "Moonshine beyond the Monster" has me stumped.  It asks whether the real Lie algebras of smooth vector fields over the reals $V(\mathbb{R})$ and over the circle $V(S^1)$ are isomorphic or not.

The two are isomorphic as real vector spaces assuming the axiom of choice, but they should not be isomorphic as Lie algebras: I know that the Lie algebra determines the topology of a manifold and the two underlying manifolds are not homeomorphic.

Pick coordinates $\theta$ and $t$ on $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ respectively to write typical elements of the corresponding algebras as $\phi(\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}$ and $f(t)\frac{d}{dt}$ respectively with smooth coefficients.

My first question is: is the map which takes $\phi(\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}$ to $\phi(t)\frac{d}{dt}$ (seen as a periodic function on the reals) a well defined map between the algebras?  If so, it seems to me that this embeds the Lie algebra $V(S^1)\hookrightarrow V(\mathbb{R})$.

My second question is, how can we show that the algebras are not isomorphic?  I tried to construct some relation involving brackets that holds in $V(\mathbb{R})$ but not $V(S^1)$ but without success.  I thought I had to force a lack of periodicity for all solutions of some differential equation given solely in terms of the bracket, but I haven't managed it so far: every relation I try is satisfied in $V(S^1)$ as well.  Am I completely off target?  If so, please provide a hint to get me closer.  If not, please suggest a relation that can do the trick.

Some more information: the section in the book that contains the exercise mentions the Witt subalgebra of the complexification of $V(S^1)$, but unless the answer to my first question is 'no', I do not see how one can use the relations there to get a contradiction in $V(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: the ad-action of $t^2\, d/dt$ on the vector fields on the real line doesn't exponentiate, whereas the ad-action of any vector field on $S^1$ does

Comment: I do not understand the suggestion.  I have to take on faith the statements about exponentiation (what does $\cos{\theta}\frac{d}{d\theta}$ exponentiate to in $Diff(S^1)$?  why doesn't the given map exponentiate in $Diff(\mathbb{R})$?), but assuming those statements: we have two Lie groups $Diff(S^1)$ and $Diff(\mathbb{R})$ whose Ads differentiate to ads of our two algebras.  One differentiation is surjective, the other is not.  How does this information allow us to conclude the Lie algebra structures are distinct?

Comment: Continuing: so for instance, if we complexify both Lie algebras, so no Lie group corresponds to $\mathbb{C}\otimes V(S^1)$, how can we show that the two complex Lie algebras are or are not isomorphic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intriguing problem. Here's a rather ad hoc proof that they're not isomorphic. There might be an easier way to do this, but this argument has the advantage that it doesn't use any sophisticated theory of infinite-dimensional Lie algebras or Lie groups.

Note that $V(\mathbb R)$ contains an element $X$ such that the map $\operatorname{ad}_X\colon V(\mathbb R)\to V(\mathbb R)$ is surjective (where $\operatorname{ad}_X(Y) = [X,Y]$): For example, $X=d/dt$ is such an element, because given any vector field $Z = w(t)d/dt$, we can let $Y = W(t)d/dt$, where $W$ is an antiderivative of $w$, and then $[X,Y]=Z$.

Now suppose $V(\mathbb R)$ and $V(S^1)$ are isomorphic. Then the isomorphism carries $X$ to some element $\overline X\in V(S^1)$ such that $\operatorname{ad}_{\overline X}\colon V(S^1)\to V(S^1)$ is surjective. We can write $\overline X = f\,d/d\theta$ for some smooth $2\pi$-periodic function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.  For any vector field $u\,d/d\theta\in V(S^1)$, $[\overline X,u\,d/d\theta] = (fu'-uf')d/d\theta$, so we conclude that for any $2\pi$-periodic smooth function $h$, there is a $2\pi$-periodic smooth function $u$ such that $fu'-uf'=h$.

First take $h\equiv 1$, so there is a $u$ satisfying $fu'-uf'=1$. At any $\theta_0$ where $f(\theta_0)=0$, this equation implies $f'(\theta_0)\ne 0$.

Next take $h=f$, so there is some $v$ satisfying 
$$fv'-vf'=f.$$
Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ yields
$$fv''-vf''=f',$$
since the $f'v'$ terms cancel. 
If there is any $\theta_0$ where $f(\theta_0)=0$, the first equation implies $v(\theta_0)=0$ also, but then the second equation implies $f'(\theta_0)=0$, contradicting the result in the previous paragraph. Therefore $f$ never vanishes.

Finally, take $h=f^2$, so there is some $w$ satisfying 
$$fw'-wf'=f^2.$$
Because $f$ never vanishes and both $f$ and $w$ are periodic, the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
\begin{align*}
0 &= \left.\frac{w}{f}\right|_0^{2\pi}
= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d}{d\theta} \left(\frac{w}{f}\right)\,d\theta
=  \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{f w'- wf'}{f^2}\,d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi} 1\,d\theta =2\pi,
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: This is it.  What I was stuck on is trying to find a reason for $f$ not to vanish, in order to carry out the last step in your deduction with $f^2$; I did not think of taking $h$ to be $1$ and $f$!.  Thank you, I will accept the answer and give the bounty because it filled precisely the gap I could not work out (I clearly did not work hard enough).  Other solutions which are more 'slick' or use heavier machinery are more than welcome to give a different perspective, but please, posters, give details!

Answer (score 0):

For any Lie algebra $L$, denote the $q$-th cohomology of $L$ by $H^q(L)$. By [De-Rham theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham%27s_theorem) we know that:
$$H^1(V(\mathbb{S}^1))=H_{De-Rham}^1(\mathbb{S}^1)\cong H_{Singular}^1(\mathbb{S}^1; \mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$$
$$H^1(V(\mathbb{R}^1))=H_{De-Rham}^1(\mathbb{R}^1)\cong H_{Singular}^1(\mathbb{R}^1; \mathbb{R})\cong 0$$

Thus, $H^1(V(\mathbb{S}^1))\not\cong H^1(V(\mathbb{R}^1))$, and so we get $V(\mathbb{S}^1)\not\cong V(\mathbb{R}^1)$